# How to get a left and right frame to fill in TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a window that has two half-window frames on either side, but I can't get them to fill. I need the two frames to take up half of the width and all of the height of the window, no matter the size of their contents. I've set up a grid layout, but the two frames aren't expanding to fill their size. Here's the code for the frames:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')

viewerPane = Frame(root,bg="red")
actionPane = Frame(root,bg="blue")

viewerPane.grid(row=0,column=0)
actionPane.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

What do I need to do to get these two frames to split the width and fill the height of the window, no matter the size of the window?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `sticky` attribute so that the frames stick to the sides of the space allocated to them.

```
...
viewerPane.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
actionPane.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="nsew")
...
```

Comment: All right, they're positioned. Now how do I actually get them to expand? They're still empty.

Comment: @MatthewFournier: if you use the sticky attribute, they will fill the window.